# Java Swing - transparent JFrame causing high CPU usage

Tags: java, windows, swing

I've been working on a simple game recently, and so far, I've had few problems getting things to work as I want them to. At the moment, it's very simple, there's just a single sprite that I can click and drag around the screen. However, I noticed something odd at one point: that the resource usage is unexpectedly high. According to Task Manager, Java's CPU usage reads around 6% and GPU usage around 34%, which is higher than nearly all programs on my computer, save for more demanding games which typically hover around 10-15% CPU and 20% GPU. For reference, idling, my computer usually sits around 2-3% total CPU usage and 1% GPU. After a good deal of process of elimination, I narrowed the problem down to calling repaint() every frame for a maximized, transparent window, which is an important aspect for the game.

I was able to reproduce the issue with a barebones program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    Body root;
    
    public Test() {
        root = new Body();
        root.setOpaque(false);
        add(root);
        
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setVisible(true);
        setExtendedState(getExtendedState()|MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        root.run();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test app = new Test();
    }
    
    class Body extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        final int DELAY = 1000/60;
        
        public Body() {}
        
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
        
        public void run() {
            long prevframe, sleep;
            while (true) {
                prevframe = System.currentTimeMillis();
                repaint();
                sleep = DELAY - (System.currentTimeMillis() - prevframe);
                if (sleep < 0) {
                    sleep = 2;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

At first, I thought it was an issue with my use of `BufferedImage`s, since they are not hardware accelerated by default, but when I stopped drawing them, the CPU/GPU usage persisted. That's when I started my process of elimination, gradually commenting out chunks of code until I found that it was just the `repaint()` call and whatever happens to be attached to it.

If the window is made opaque (i.e., removing the `root.setOpaque(false)` and `setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))` lines), the resource usage drops to about 2% CPU and 20% GPU, which is still significantly higher than I would expect out of a window that isn't doing anything except showing a blank screen every frame, especially in terms of GPU usage.

I also tried, on a whimsy, enabling OpenGL hardware acceleration by putting `System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True")` in main() before the Test() object is created, but there is no noticeable impact.

Also, I will call myself out on not using `invokeLater()` to start the Swing application (bad practice, because Swing components are supposed to have all their processing done on the Event Dispatch Thread). I realized late into putting the game together that I neglected to do that, but when I went and tried to basically retrofit it into `main()`, the graphics won't update. I'm not sure if it has to do with the way my classes are currently organized or what, but I spent minimal effort on that front since it runs fine at the moment without the EDT, save for the CPU/GPU usage. Unless this may be the cause of my problem, in which case that needs to be fixed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. This is my first post of Stack Overflow, so I'm not totally sure if there is anything I am missing. That said, if any other information or testing is needed on my part, I will gladly provide.

I am currently working with:

- Java 18 and 19 (Oracle's official SE Development Kit)
- OS: Windows 11
- GPU: Intel UHD Graphics (i7-10750H).

I will note that my computer does have a GTX 1650 Ti as a dedicated card, but everything mentioned above has been running off of the Intel chip.

Comment: Swing does not handle transparent colors very well.  You can fake transparency by drawing a background from your display image.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Unfortunately, for the game to work as intended, the background does need to be truly transparent and click-through, because the end user will need to be able to interact with applications underneath the game window. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting with fake transparency?

Comment: You can try JavaFX or Apache Pivot.  Swing does not handle transparent colors very well.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm currently slowly converting everything to JavaFX, mostly because of some unrelated functionality that Swing doesn't directly support. However, I will still leave this question up because I am still curious as to what the issue is (note that it still has high GPU usage with an opaque window) and in case someone else has this same problem.